# Compiling FFTW without root access

Tags: unix, linker, compilation, fftw

my boss is in vacation and I would really like to compile the FFTW library from http://www.fftw.org/ on a Mac OS X . The problem is, I don't have root access to install the files in the root directories with make install. Is there any possibility to install them local just for my user account? .

I read this http://www.princeton.edu/~ngrube/notes.html#fftw ..

I get a folder with a bin, lib, include and share subfolder in my home directory. In the include folder is the fftw3.h file and in the lib folder the libfftw3.a file. Is there a possibility to use the fftw3.h in my project? When I run it and want to link the libfftw3.a to my project it says :

library not found for -llibfftw3.a

I'm using Eclipse CDT for C/C++

edit:

I just saw, that when I use the make install for installing on some local path in my user directory I get some lines:

```
ranlib: file: #path#/FFTWLIB/lib/libfftw3.a(debug.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: #path#FFTWLIB/lib/libfftw3.a(altivec.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: #path#FFTWLIB/lib/libfftw3.a(avx.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: #path#FFTWLIB/lib/libfftw3.a(sse2.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: #path#FFTWLIB/lib/libfftw3.a(taint.o) has no symbols
```

I think they are the problem. Someone has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to make sure that the lib directory is in the linker path.  You can set this somewhere in the Eclipse project settings.